# How I can work with id of rows in SQLite(JAVA)?

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite

```
@DatabaseField
private String Name;
@DatabaseField()
private String Surname;
@DatabaseField(id=true)
String ID;
```

I have this columns and I defined `'id = true'` for `String ID` field. Now I want to update certain row, but I can't find nessecary row. My ID column takes values like `(12BD02000, 12BD02001.....)`. But I need id like `(1,2,3....,)` in order work with them. How I can do it without defining auto-incremented special row for another id?

Answer (score 0):

In this case id type should be `long`:

```
@DatabaseField(generatedId=true,unique=true)
private Long id;
```

[DatabaseField](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html#id()) official documentation.